# MS Access: How do I remove the 13 leading spaces of this field?

Tags: string, ms-access, replace, ms-access-2013, trim

I have a table where one of the fields has 13 leading spaces (no visible characters in them). I tried `TRIM()` and `REPLACE([Field1], "             ", "")` but neither one worked. Could anyone venture a guess as to what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: if it is 13 every time then use the MID function: Mid([Field1], 14)

Comment: @Sorceri I just double checked. Some have 13 leading spaces, some have 11.

Comment: `TRIM` should work, so your problem lies somewhere else (maybe it's not spaces but some other whitespace character?). I'm afraid, a [mcve] will be necessary to find the cause.

Comment: Try `CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE([Field1],CHAR(127),CHAR(7)))`. Also, it would help if you copied the cell value, pasted into http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ and see what characters you really have there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but it will allow you to see what the chr value is for the string.  Just call it like MsgBox WhatAreTheAscValues([Field1]) and you will see what value the characters that make up the string and allow you to adjust your code accordingly.

```
Function WhatAreTheAscValues(str As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim answer As String
    answer = "The Chr(x) values in this string are listed below" & vbCrLf
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        answer = answer + CStr(Asc(Mid(str, i, 1))) & ", "
    Next i
    WhatAreTheAscValues = Left(answer, Len(answer) - 2)
End Function
```